# input type radio no binding ng-model angularjs

Tags: angularjs

ng-model does not change my radio button, selecting another option print the value in the ng-model does not change
my HTML

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" role="group">
  <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary ">
    <input type="radio" name="turno"  ng-model="vm.turno" value="matutino" />
    <i class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i>Matutino
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary active">
     <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.turno" value="vespertino" />
     <i class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i>Vespertino
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.turno" value="nocturno" />
    <i class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i>Nocturno
 </label>
</div>

<span>{{vm.turno}}</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your answers, I was able to resolve the detail was ui.bootstrap use, instead of using a regular radio input, use a label with btn-radio, I remain as follows.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" btn-radio="'matutino'" ng-model="vm.turno">
   <i class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i>Matutino
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary active" btn-radio="'vespertino'" ng-model="vm.turno">
   <i class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i>Vespertino
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-outline btn-primary" btn-radio="'nocturno'" ng-model="vm.turno">
   <i class="icon wb-check text-active" aria-hidden="true"></i>Nocturno
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You left out `name` on 2 of the radios. That is what groups them together

Comment: That is not the problem, it works fine if I remove the data-toggle = "buttons" of the div, known to be overheard.

Comment: then create a demo that replicates problem. Not really clear what it is from the description

Answer (score 1):

have you set `vm = this` in your controller?  
or maybe you have set the `vm.turno` to the other type 
it works well in my code 
[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/mzv5A9PcU8uKXV3jxr67?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

`vm.turno` it is radio button whose default value is

```
boolean true or false.
```

These boolean value can not be printable in html.

You can try like this if you want to see the change

```
{{vm.turno ? "true" : "false"}}
```